# Не пойму где ошибка в коде. Пишет System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Строка содержит синтаксическую ошибку в выражении запроса

Tags: c#, access

```
        //Выполянем запрос к БД
       dbConnection.Open();//открываем соеденение
        string query = "UPDATE [Title] SET [Title] = '" + Title + "', [Index] ='" + Index + "', [Description] ='" + Description + "', [ChemicalClass] ='" + ChemicalClass + "', [Price] ='" + Price + "', [Cod] ='" + Cod;//строка запроса
        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);//команда

        //Здесь ошибка
    if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)


        //Выполянем запрос к БД
        dbConnection.Open();//открываем соеденение
        string query = "INSERT INTO Title VALUES (" + Cod + ", '" + Title + "','" + Index + "','" + Description + "','" + ChemicalClass+ "','" + Price + "')";//строка запроса
        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);//команда

        //И здесь ошибка
        if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
```

Comment: Я прописал моменты в коде где выдаёт ошибку в качестве заметки

Comment: Точку остановки ставите, и смотрите что у вас в `query`, изучаете полученный результат, и ищите ошибки.  Например, где у вас в конце `'`? Открыть открыли, а закрыть? Ну и да, так запросы не пишут, это не безопасно! Стоит подумать об использовании аргументов запроса.

Comment: Спасибо но я не особо понял что должно быть в query и как закрыть здесь чтобы не выдало ошибку в данной строке 
 string query = "UPDATE [Title] SET [Title] = '" + Title + "', [Index] ='" + Index + "', [Description] ='" + Description + "', [ChemicalClass] ='" + ChemicalClass + "', [Price] ='" + Price + "', [Cod] ='" + Cod;

Comment: В `query`, под отладкой, вам покажет готовую строку, в которую были вставлены все ваши `+ .. +`, вы сразу будете видеть, верно там все или нет. "Как закрыть" - наверно `+ Cod + "'";`, если брать ваш "стиль". А вообще, поизучайте "интерполяцию строк", тогда будет что-то по типу `$"UPDATE [Title] SET [Title] = '{Title}', [Index] ='{Index}', ..."`, согласитесь, куда приятней выглядит, чем то, что у вас. Ну и да, напомню про аргументы, сейчас в ваш запрос легко внедрить вредоносный код, это дыра в безопасности.

Comment: Большое спасибо помогли.